# Android how to display Icon in Signal icon area?

Tags: android, user-interface

I have following queries.

1. How can I display icon in Signal Area(what it is called?) ? Like default audio player when playback is on and u press HOME or BACK at last screen of audio player, Play icon is displayed in that areA? Kind of minimize application.
2. How to display shortcut of media player? the minimal version of media player in that area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're called notifications, and the documentation has a very detailed guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: Thanks EboMike, where should one generate such notification, up on pressing HOME key ? I can generate when BACK button is pressed from my fist activity. How about say 3rd activity is displayed and HOME key is pressed and playback is on, where should i put generation of notification code in this situation?

Comment: Don't do keypresses. It sounds like you want to do it on `onPause` of your activity, and remove it in `onResume`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the source code for ApiDemos. You will find exactly what you are looking for, and more.

Comment: Thanks Robert, where should one generate such notification, up on pressing HOME key ? I can generate when BACK button is pressed from my fist activity. How about say 3rd activity is displayed and HOME key is pressed and playback is on, where should i put generation of notification code in this situation?

Comment: I would probably put it in onStop().